# how laravel join three tables with advance join clause using variable

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Larvel have a question about inner joins with multiple tables and on values. I did build my code like this in laravel.

```
$clients = clients::leftjoin('clients_payment_type','clients_topup', function($join) {
        $join->on('clients_payment_type.user_id', '=', 'clients.id') AND
        $join->on('clients_topup.user_id', '=', 'clients.id');
      })->where('clients.reference_id','=',$reference_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Answer

```
  $clients1 = DB::table('clients')
          ->leftjoin('clients_payment_type','clients_payment_type.user_id', '=', 'clients.id')
          ->leftjoin('clients_topup', 'clients_topup.user_id', '=', 'clients.id')
          ->where('clients.reference_id','=',$reference_id)
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$clients = clients::leftjoin('clients_payment_type','clients_topup')
->join('clients','clients_payment_type.user_id', '=', 'clients.id')
->join('client_toup','clients.id', '=', 'clients_topup.user_id')
->where('clients.reference_id','=',$reference_id)
->get();
```

Regards

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'clients' (SQL: select * from `clients` left join `clients_payment_type` on `clients_topup` = `` inner join `clients` on `clients_payment_type`.`user_id` = `clients`.`id` inner join `clients_topup` on `clients`.`id` = `clients_topup`.`user_id` where `clients`.`reference_id` = IEWR927) ◀"

Comment: My bad try this :
`$clients = clients::leftjoin('clients_payment_type','clients_topup')
->join('client_toup','clients.id', '=', 'clients_topup.user_id')
->where('clients.reference_id','=',$reference_id)
->get();`